# how to display spaces and paragraph in the description

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

**Description in the database is like this : -**

Compared with the billions of other stars in the universe, the sun is unremarkable.

But for Earth and the other planets that revolve around it, the sun is a powerful center of attention.

It holds the solar system together; pours life-giving light, heat, and energy on Earth; and generates space weather.

**but while displaying in the report it comes like this : -**

Compared with the billions of other stars in the universe, the sun is unremarkable.But for Earth and the other planets that revolve around it, the sun is a powerful center of attention.It holds the solar system together; pours life-giving light, heat, and energy on Earth; and generates space weather.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is returning `\n`, the newline character.

HTML will parse the newline character as a new line if it is within a `<p></p>`.

You have two choices:

1) Put the output in a `<p>`.

or

2) Search and replace all instances of \n with `<br />`:

```
someString.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `simple_format(model.description)` in `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` if you are gonna display it in a view.

[Documentation for simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simple_format` to display the text using simple formatting rules. Two or more consecutive newlines (\n\n) are considered a paragraph and wrapped in

tags. One newline (\n) is considered a linebreak and a 
 tag is appended.

```
= simple_format(text)
```